# How do I install packages from source on macOS?

Tags: r, macos

I had some problems with knitting the file, so I reinstalled it. I installed the latest version of R studio and it required me install xfun package. I installed it a lot of time but it is still not working. I attached the feedback below.

[image]

Comment: It seems that there is a problem with the installation of the package `xfun`. Try this: `install.packages("xfun")` before knitting the file in RMarkdown.

Comment: I tried. It asked me to install again.

Comment: Install the binary version of the package. — This has nothing to do with knitting, or RStudio. And please in the future include error messages *as text*, not as an image.

Comment: You haven't installed Xcode. Follow the instructions: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#Prerequisites